# How get better NullPointerException messages on desktop JVMs?

Tags: java, error-handling, nullpointerexception, runtime-error

As you may or may not know Android ART virtual machines have an awesome feature: namely they tell you exactly what was `null`:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'ReturnValue fully.qualified.ClassName.andMethod(overload)' on a null object reference
>       at net.twisterrob.Test.main(Test.java:19)

Compare this to the standard Oracle desktop JVM:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at net.twisterrob.Test.main(Test.java:19)

I'm wondering if there's a way to have this behavior enabled in Oracle JDK at least while debugging or is there an alternative compatible JDK/JVM that provides this feature.

Comment: If anyone knows a better answer it's up for grabs ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no way to get a better NPE message using a Oracle HotSpot Java.

Comment: Do you maybe know of any other VM that may have this?

Comment: The Android VMs do,  Real Java?  AFAIK, none.  It would be incompatible behavior, and most likely result in a JTK failure.  (Android doesn't care about that .....)

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting, I wouldn't have thought a message would be considered that, but thinking about it applications may rely on it and parse it. Can you please link to whatever JTK is, if it's public? I couldn't find any trace of it, only "Mines Java Toolkit", which I feel is not related here.

Comment: Sorry.  I got the acronym wrong.  It is the JCK: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technology_Compatibility_Kit#TCK_for_the_Java_platform.  There most likely is toolchain and application code that *depends* on the fact that the JVM throws NPEs with a `null` message.  It has behaved that way since Java 1.0.  Changing this would break compatibility for this code.